# Cannot scale font in body tag with @-moz-document url-prefix()

Tags: css, firefox, browser

I want to scale down my fonts for the mozilla browser by say, 10%.
So I have the following code in my stylesheet:

```
body{   font-size: 62.5%; }
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    body{   font-size: 56.25%; }
}
```

But for some reason, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Changes on individual divs work fine though.
Example:

```
#footer-links{  font-size: 1em; }
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    #footer-links{  font-size: .9em; }
}
```

I will probably just end up doing this for all divs then...
But I'm just puzzled why the body setting above isn't working.

**EDIT:**

I've also just tried with the html tag:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
   html{    font-size: 56.25%; }
}
```

Although this does rescale the font, it's not to the size specified, but to much smaller than the original.

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried `* { }`?

Comment: @jmeas - Thanks for the comment.  No, I haven't tried this.  Can you put it in an answer if it will work?  I'm not familiar with using the * in css.

Comment: Can you post a link to a testcase?  This should work fine, depending on what exactly the rest of your CSS and markup looks like.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Created a test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/grainne/myccK/26/    I've noticed it's only happening when I use rems.  When I change to em, it scales fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the fiddle.

`rem` units are root em.  That is, they're in terms of the font size of the root element.  Which in HTML is `html`, not `body`.  So changing the font size of `body` doesn't change the size of a `rem`.